# Can Apache CXF generate a client and automatically get local copies of WSDLs and schemas?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

I have inherited a project that relies on an Apache CXF generated client. Instantiation of this client is SLOW. I think this is because the WSDLs, schemas, and DTDs are not stored locally they are fetched remotely every time.

Is there a way to generate a CXF client which automatically creates a local copy of the WSDL and schemas when the client is generated?

Is there a tool other than CXF that can generate java code which automatically pulls theses resources locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `wsdl2java` plugin, either you can provide the url or local copy reference of wsdl. For more info refer plugin documentation [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html) and sample program [here](https://github.com/kprasad99/kp-soap-ws-client)